# OpenLayers 3 support for WMS 1.3.0 CRS:1

Tags: openlayers, wms

I am trying to get a TileWMS layer working with the CS as CRS:1 defined in WMS 1.3.0. By defining the right projection stated in CRS:1, axisorientation as 'es', I could get it working for ImageWMS. However, when using TileWMS, I found all the tileGrids defined in OpenLayers​ 3 are always aligned with 'en' direction. tileindex x increments as x goes right, tileindex y increments as y goes up. So it is different from the CRS:1 definition. This causes the tiles are put into wrong direction in y axis.

My question is that is there any way that I can change tiling direction to follow the axixorientation defined in my projection, in this case, is 'es'? Or are there any advice or examples for 'es' projection like CRS:1 in tiled API of OpenLayers 3?

Comment: Is the request made by OpenLayers a version 1.3.0 one?